# Getting full stack trace in BatchApexErrorEvent

Tags: exception, batchapexerrorevent

I am using the BatchApexErrorEvent to get the stack trace of the exception but it only gives the line from where the issue is generated.

```
{
    ReplayId=12, 
    CreatedDate=2019-06-18 12:45:24, 
    CreatedById=0059D000000ExddQAC, 
    ExceptionType=System.NullPointerException, 
    Message=Attempt to de-reference a null object, 

    // This is the line
    StackTrace=Class.heymarket.S2HSync.mergeSF2HM: line 113, column 1, 
    RequestId=4P_Ada16R2VRFe-qbw, 
    AsyncApexJobId=7079D000003vUTO, 
    DoesExceedJobScopeMaxLength=false
}
```

I want the full stack trace of the issue from the calling method to the line which is throwing the exception.

Is there any available solution for this?

Comment: Is it managed code? If so, you probably cannot get detailed stack trace information.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes it is being returned from the standard BatchApexErrorEvent.